# How can I sort an array according to values of its corresponding vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stdvector

I want to sort my `row` array according to the values of the corresponding vector. That means, I have a vector that contains vector of integers of the same length. `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec`.
And according to the values of `vect` I want to sort my array `row`. `row` contains `N` elements, where the first element gives the number that we should consider for our row. If `row[0]==2` then we should only care 2 elements after `row[0]`.

> Example:
>
> ```
> Input:   vect = {{0,2,3},{2,1,5},{1,2,4}} 
>          row  = {3,0,1,2,-1,-2,15}
> ```

Note that in `row` we just care about 2nd to 4th element since its first element is 3 (which represents the size of `vect`. i.e, `row[0] = vect.size()`).

I want to sort my array and vector according to the values `023, 215 and 124`. That is, after sorting my vector, according to its elements' new positions I should sort my array by considering its first element. (just sort the desired ones.)

So what I want to get is:

> ```
> Output: vect = {{0,2,3},{1,2,4},{2,1,5}}
>         row  = {3,0,2,1,-1,-2,15}
> ```

Thank you very much for any help. Following is the code:

```
std::vector<int> seq;
int pair;
while(pair!=-1) {
    seq.push_back(letter[pair--]);
}

.
.
.
int* row = new int[N]; // N is the input
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vect;
vect.resize(row[0]);
for(int e=0;e<row[0];e++){
    for(int elm=0;elm<seq.size();elm++)
        vect[e].push_back(outputs[seq[elm]][row[e+1]]);
}
sort(vect,row); // sort both?
```

Comment: The explanation you've given for your problem is worded in a confusing manner, making it difficult to understand what you're asking and what your problem is. You should edit your question to contain clear, distinct statements that explain what your **code is meant to do**, what **output you expect**, and what **incorrect output you're getting**. If you do that, it will be much more likely that you can get a useful answer.

Comment: I think we need a clear example of input, process, and desired output. IMy read of the question is that you want to sort the `vector`s in `vect` according to the indices in `row`, but this makes no sense in the face of  negative numbers in `row`.

Comment: Many phrases in this question give me pause.  I'm not confident that I understand what's being said.  "desired ones", "we just care", "that is", "integers of same length", and four distinct "I want..."  Perhaps there is trouble writing this code because there is difficulty describing the problem?

Comment: didn't get the whole, but from what I understood, I wanna know; what if `row[0]==5`? there you have some negative values in your array and you don't have that many rows in your 2D vector array.

Comment: I'm afraid that after the update I still can't understand what you are asking. It reads as though if given 3, you want to sort elements 3, 4, and 5, but the sample of `vect` has no 3,4,and 5.

Comment: @JeJo Actually, `row[0]` is always same with `vect.size()` It is written in my code as `vect.resize(row[0]);`

Comment: @Tripoli *vector according to the values 23, 215 and 124* here you simply treat whole 2D vector rows as a single integer elements, right?

Comment: @JeJo Yes, I want to treat them just like an integer.

Comment: @user4581301 I want to sort the vector and looking the new positions and old positions of its values, I want to sort first `row[0]` elements of my array starting from index 1. So `vect[0]` corresponds to `row[1]`, `vect[1]` corresponds to `row[2]`, and so on. If `vect[0]` is new `vect[1]`, `row [1]` should be new `row[2]`.

Comment: As I understand, following should help [sorting-zipped-locked-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840998/sorting-zipped-locked-containers-in-c-using-boost-or-the-stl)

Comment: Here is a link to an example of [sorting multiple arrays according to one of the arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336770/sort-multiple-arrays-simultaneously-in-place/50340797#50340797) which might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will give your desired output or at least give away(may be un-efficient) to approach your problem. Hope, the comments can guide you through.

[<kbd>**See Output**</kbd>](https://www.ideone.com/UXAHld)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>>  vect = {{0,2,3},{2,1,5},{1,2,4}};
   std::vector<int> row = {3,0,1,2,-1,-2,15};
   // new vector:  pair of integer -> representing the rows of vect and index
   std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> newVect;
   newVect.reserve(vect.size());

   int index = 0;
   for(const std::vector<int>& each_row: vect)
   {
      std::string str;             // each row of vect to a single integer string
      for(const int Integer: each_row) str += std::to_string(Integer);
      newVect.emplace_back(std::make_pair(str, index));
      ++index;
   }
   // sort the new vector, according to the whole 2D vector row(which is a single string)
   std::sort(newVect.begin(), newVect.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs)
   {
      return lhs.first < rhs.first;
   });
   // now you can actually store the sorted vect
   vect.clear();
   for(auto index = 1; index <= row[0]; ++index)
   {
      row[index] = newVect[index-1].second;  // replace the row indexes which are sorted
      std::vector<int> vect_row;
      // change each chars of string back to corresponding row elements
      for(const char Integer: newVect[index-1].first)
         vect_row.emplace_back(static_cast<int>(Integer - '0'));
      // store to original vector
      vect.emplace_back(vect_row);
   }

   // to print
   for(const std::vector<int>& each_row: vect)
   {
      for(const int Intger: each_row)
         std::cout << Intger << " ";
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   for(const int it: row) std::cout << it << " ";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Tripoli Hope that was helpful. :)